# Update statement generating null violations on pre-populated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update rows in PostgreSQL DB. When I try to run an update query to update values in 2 columns (with no constraints). My table structure is as follows (variable names changed)

schema.table 
 |-> id (not null)  
 |-> company (varchar) 
 |-> model 
 |-> serial_number 
 |-> series

There is unique constraint on model and serial_number.

```
UPDATE schema.table 
SET company = 'Apple' WHERE model like 'iPhone%' AND series like 'X%';
```

The above snippet generates the following error even when the row already has a serial_number.

```
Reason:
SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: null value in column "serial_number" violates not-null constraint
```

I'd like to set company to "Apple" were model='iPhone' and series is like 'X%'.

Comment: Can you provide DDL for the table and/or sample data for replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
UPDATE schema.table 
    SET company = 'Apple'
    WHERE model like 'iPhone%' AND series like 'X%';
```

Does not change the `serial_number` at all.  Hence, I conclude that you have an `update` trigger on the table that is causing the problem.  So, look into any triggers that are there.

Comment: Thank you, very much. Turns out `serial_number` had a trigger on `INSERT/UPDATE` to validate the new value being entered.